# Create a windows like screen saver to open an application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I want to open an url in a browser after no activity in windows , and that using windows services

Any idea how that will be in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need thread that checks for activity, Make a class with a method in it, Make a timespan that checks time since the last key was pressed and use an if statement to launch a browser if the time passes a certain amount.

Comment: I didn't put code in on purpose because i do not want to do your homework, If you submit some code that you have tried, i will help you and submit code. :) no hard feelings :)

Comment: But if you need some further help just say :) i didn't want to come off too mean